# Anaconda python has module installed but import fails

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I've installed and am seeing the elasticsearch module when I do a conda list, but when I try to import it in my program or ipython I get a module not found error.
I've done this successfully recently on another machine but I think I've overlooked a step on this go round. Thanks.

[image]

However, the following works without error:

```
(talon) ubuntu@~/flask-temp-dir-no-git$ python -c "import elasticsearch"
(talon) ubuntu@~/flask-temp-dir-no-git$ which python
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/talon/bin/python


 python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

This code actually is part of a Flask app, if that makes any difference in the solution.

Comment: Check if your module directory is added to the `sys.path` list

Comment: What do I do with that information about the path?  How do I troubleshoot?  My knowledge of module management is limited

Comment: Did you also install `ipython` into your `talon` environment?

Comment: `import sys` and then append the path to module to `sys.path` list. This might hopefully make this right.

Comment: Thanks this has been resolved.  However I'm not sure what resolved it.  I believe the shell got in a bad state and launching a new shell fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this has been resolved. However I'm not sure what resolved it. I believe the shell got in a bad state and launching a new shell fixed it.